# Not able to run scripts across the different Browsers

Tags: google-chrome, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I am not able to run the script using WebDriver  across different Browsers.For IE its working fine.

Firstly I automated an application for IE.then I tried to run the same script in Chrome or FireFox.
Now on Chrome and FireFox some of the elements are not getting recognized by the WebDriver.

***1. How can this be resoled?***

***2. Is there any solution for this so that I can run the same script on different browsers  irrespective of the Browsers?***

Please suggest.

Comment: When running JavaScript one has to be very careful about using only elements handled by all of your intended browsers .. or to special case the items that are not universal. Can you show your JavaScript that you are having a problem with?

Comment: You would need to post some code for us to be able to help you. Everything else is just a guessing game.

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing the page it would be hard to tell, it depends on your situation, normally there is one selector that will work across your browsers but its technically possible for your development team to be using completely different element names ids etc etc depending on browser (or even completely different pages), it would be crazy for them to be doing it on purpose but it is possible so you will find people may be unable to help without more information.

Typically css selectors are the most robust selector across browsers while xpath is the most flakey. post some code both of your test and pages and can probably help further

Answer (score -1):

Sometimes, the locator you are using will work in one browser , but not in other browsers. Try using different locators such that it gets executed in all the three browsers.

Comment: this...what my query is? if I have 1000 elements and I want to run the script in 3 browsers then it will take lot of time.. can u have some other approach. ?